# How to get subtotal when variable not in foreach loop ? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a cart and I need to get a subtotal of items added to cart. How to do that when variable is outside of foreach loop ? At first I'm looping every product like this:

```
@foreach($products as $p)
{{$p['title']}}
{{$p['price']}}
@endforeach
```

And then how do I need to get the subtotal of all products price outside this loop ?

Comment: can you access `price` of individual products inside  your foreach loop now?

Comment: Yeah, I just updated my question @Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a clean solution for this if you want to achieve this in view however you can still use this code inside your `view` template as well.

You can pass the `subtotal` value explicitly from your controller method and display it in view. It could have been done like this. Add this code inside your controller function.

```
//initialize an empty array
$subtotal = [];
foreach($products as $p){
$price = $p['price'];
$title = $p['title'];
//push the price item to your subtotal array
array_push($subtotal, $price);
}
```

now you can use `array_sum()` to get the subtotal of your product like

```
$finalTotal = array_sum($subtotal);   //returns sum of an array
```

now i hope you are passing `products` from inside your controller. You just need to pass `$finalTotal` now. For example

```
return view('yourview')->with(array(
     'products'    => $products,
     'finalTotal' => $finalTotal 
));
```

Now in your blade template you can access `subtotal` by just doing `{{$finalTotal}}`. I hope you get it

You can embed this code in order to get total in view. I hope this will help you

Comment: Is there're possible way to add this to controller ?

Comment: i suppose you are passing your `product` variable from controller right?